# Maximum depth of a binary search tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to write  a recursive function to fetch the maximum depth of a binary search tree. I not exactly sure on the difference between these two implementations. Shouldn't both of them return the same result?

Code 1:

```py
def maxDepth(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        l = r = 0
        if root:
            print(root.val)
            if root.left:
                print(f"In left subtree for root {root.val}")
                l = self.maxDepth(root.left)
                print(f"l: {l}  r: {r}")
            if root.right:
                print(f"In right subtree for root {root.val}")
                r = self.maxDepth(root.right)
                print(f"l: {l}  r: {r}")
            else:
                print("No subtree")       
        return max(l,r) + 1
```

Code 2:

```py
def maxDepth(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        l = r = 0
        if root:
            print(root.val)
            if root.left:
                print(f"In left subtree for root {root.val}")
                l = self.maxDepth(root.left) + 1
                print(f"l: {l}  r: {r}")
            if root.right:
                print(f"In right subtree for root {root.val}")
                r = self.maxDepth(root.right) + 1
                print(f"l: {l}  r: {r}")
            else:
                print("No subtree")       
        return max(l,r)
```

Comment: No, if `root` is `None` or a leaf, the first returns `1`, the second `0`. Also the `else`-block makes no sense as it outputs "No subtree" whenever there is no right child, regardless of any left child

Comment: The else block was just for debugging i.e. to check whenever i reached a leaf node. Can you elaborate why it is regardless of any left child? @schwobaseggl TIA

Comment: Also the +1 was for adding the depth of the current root. I am still unclear

Comment: You misunderstood what @schwobaseggl was saying. Imagine that root is None. In this case it doesn't go into the `if root` statement. It does, however, go into `max(l, r) + 1`. So in the case where `root` is `None`, the options are either `max(0, 0) + 1` or `max(0, 0)`, which are not the same.

Comment: the else-block only cares about the preceding if. So if the if `root.right` is not truthy, it will always go into the else block, because the else-block has nothing to do with the `if root.left`.